# Как перейти к следующему блоку в диалоге с телеграм ботом?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Подскажите, пожалуйста, как наладить переход к следующему диалоговому блоку?
В случае, если пользователь корректно начал диалог, после приветствия бота должен быть следующий этап с регистрацией (/reg).

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text == "Привет":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет! Спасибо, что присоединился к нашему проекту! Для регистрации напиши '/reg'")
    elif message.text == "/help":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Напиши ""Привет""")
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Я тебя не понимаю. Напиши /help.")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text == "/reg":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Как тебя зовут?");
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_name); #следующий шаг – функция get_name
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Напиши /reg');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text == "Привет":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет! Спасибо, что присоединился к нашему проекту! Для регистрации напиши '/reg'")
    elif message.text == "/help":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Напиши ""Привет""")
    elif message.text == "/reg":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Как тебя зовут?");
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_name); #следующий шаг – функция get_name
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Я тебя не понимаю. Напиши /help.")
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! :)